# Google hangouts Video lines then white

Tags: webcam, google-hangouts

I've a logitech webcam

```
➜  ~ lsusb  | grep cam
Bus 002 Device 006: ID 046d:0825 Logitech, Inc. Webcam C270
```

It works with [Cheese](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Cheese) and used to work with google hangouts. Now with google hangouts I get many flickering horizontal lines, that slowly disappear to white. Occasionally if I wait a few minutes it will start working correctly and I'll see the video from the webcam displayed on screen. I don't have enough reputation to post an image, but here's a link to [google hangouts video error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EfBDD.gif) gif.

Any suggests about how to go about debugging this welcome.

Edit: Have not resolved issue with logitech, but did buy another camera and that is working fine.

```
➜  ~ lsusb | grep -i cam
Bus 002 Device 015: ID 045e:0779 Microsoft Corp. LifeCam HD-3000
```

Answer (score 0):

Just tested the Logitech with Cheese again and the image has degraded. It looks like the camera is broken and slowly getting worse. Cheese handles this failure better, initially picture was good in Cheese while bad with lines in Chrome, now the image while not a bad as when viewed in Chrome, is getting worse in Cheese. The issue was Hardware failure.